How can I write a generic event listener react hook with type inference?
I'm trying to write a generic react hook that can be used with any event emitter that conforms to certain interface:
import { useEffect } from 'react'

type EventsMap = Record<string, (...args: any) => void>
type EventName<EM extends EventsMap> = keyof EM
type EventListener<EM extends EventsMap, EN extends EventName<EM>> = EM[EN]

export type EventEmitter<EM extends EventsMap> = {
  on<K extends keyof EM>(event: K, cb: EM[K]): () => void
}

export function useEventListener<
  EM extends EventsMap,
  EN extends EventName<EM>,
>(
  emitter: EventEmitter<EM> | undefined | null,
  eventName: EN,
  listener: EventListener<EM, EN>,
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    return emitter?.on(eventName, listener)
  })
}

The above code works, but the types are only correct if i manually specify them when calling:
  useEventListener<MyEventMap, keyof MyEventMap>(emitter, 'myEvent', () => {
    console.log('hi there')
  })

For some reason, TypeScript accepts the emitter as an instance of the event emitter, but it can't infer the EventMap from it in order to constrain the event name.
I have the impression that this is related to the problem described in this question, but I can't quite express how.
Edit
Here's a TypeScript playground with the code above plus an example event emitter.
You can see the problem manifesting in the last few lines, as the useEventListener call infers the default type for an EventMap, and therefore the event that the listener receives is typed as any.

Your question seems to be that you want the types inferred from the type of emitter that you pass in as a parameter. So what is the value for emitter that works here? And what happens to the types if you leave out the explicit generics? An example event map and emitter would make this way way easier to figure out. Add that detail to you question and we can probably help more.

@AlexWayne I added a typescript playground with an example scenario without the explicit generics .
